# Wordpress Dies When trying to edit the homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, memory

The problem is very very weird. Let me explain a little bit better - We have a multi site built for the client. Until recently we could edit the homepage with no issues. In the meantime we have upgraded the core (it was still working with new core). Just recently whenever I try to edit the homepage I get this error

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 42467328) (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in    /home/officete/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1557
```

Ok so the apparent solution was to change the php memory allowance... Well I have increased it on the server via WHM, increased it in `htaccess`, `wp-config` and `php.ini` file to over 1.2GB (never really expected I will have to increase it so much) just for testing reasons. Every time I try to edit the page I get the same god damn error and 42467328 allocation limit doesn't change at all the " 64 bytes" part does though and its between 32-128 bytes so far.

I am stumped. And have no idea what else I can do. I did contact the server provider they say it looks ok from their end.

I am assuming its the amount of data that is being collected it does contain few ACF repeater fields (15 of them... I know... But I haven't built it). I did disable all the plugins the error persists (I know that disabling them don't really change what is being pulled from db).

BTW The line 1557 is the return result function that returns the query in an array.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you changed the memory limit? You say that the first number (42467328) doesn't change and that is the number that actually tells how much memory is reserved (40 MB in your case).

Comment: It seems that the problem is quite new. An user found a dirty fix http://wordpress.org/support/topic/why-is-wp_edit_posts_query-queryposts_per_page-1 but no real explanation for the moment

Comment: Yes I did update absolutely everywhere including the define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');

Comment: Create a simple PHP script containing only `echo ini_get('memory_limit');`, upload it to your server and check what number will it output.

Comment: I finally got it fixed - so for anyone of you who experience the same problem - The solution was to move all the stuff from the php.ini and moving it to .user.ini file (I know who ever did that) but afterwards it started to work.

Comment: Please add that comment to a separate post and mark it as the answer to your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you page need more execution time.add below code into config file and try:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

Comment: I tried that it came out to be my server settings and I finally got it fixed - so for anyone of you who experience the same problem - The solution was to move all the stuff from the php.ini and moving it to .user.ini file (I know who ever did that) but afterwards it started to work